# Running Screenkey on elementary OS

Tags: release-juno, input, ibus

I'd love to easily use screenkey on elementary OS to include key presses on screenrecordings but there seem to be input method issues.

Installing screenkey (0.9-2) by using `sudo apt install screenkey` and then starting it from the command line I'm seeing this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Screenkey/keylistener.py", line 245, in run
    raise Exception("Cannot initialize input method")
Exception: Cannot initialize input method
```

When I try the same with a cloned version of the latest version from [gitlab.com/wavexx/screenkey](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/screenkey) I get a helpfull popup pointing to a troubleshoot page:
https://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/screenkey/#troubleshooting

This asked me to check the following environment variables, which should be consistent:

```
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
GTK_IM_MODULE=
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

So it's not, and apparently  I'm not running ibus:

```
$ pgrep -ax ibus-daemon
```

Finally following their advice and resetting all these environment variables before running it does work.

```
unset XMODIFIERS
unset GTK_IM_MODULES
unset QT_IM_MODULES
screenkey
```

Is there something wrong with the default elementary OS configuration?
Could I have done anything wrong? I find that these environment variables are the same on a fresh image started in a vm. 
I didn't find changes to these variables in `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.pam_environment`.

I've opened an old issue of mine that I forgot about: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/27

Comment: There's nothing wrong with elementary OS default OS configuration I think. I just installed on my computer with no problem - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6GHsCCVRSd/

Comment: @Cog You only tried installing it? You get the error I mentioned when you try to start it. I've reopened an old issue of mine: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/27

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Yes, I also face the errors while starting it from the command line. I think Its best to close the question here, its not likely to be solved over Q&A.